# Change of Assembly Name causes Runtime Exception (Culture)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

I'm trying to change the name of the main assembly in a C# / WPF click once project so we can run both release and QA versions on the same machine.

I've read many sites suggesting the only thing needed is to change the Assembly Name and the Product Name via:

Properties >> Application >> Assembly Name

and

Properties >> Application >> Assembly Name >> Assembly Information

However, when ever I change the Assembly Name I get a runtime exception on the InitializeComponent(); line within MainWindow();

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.'
>   Inner Exception
>   FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AFIL, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

AFIL was the old Assembly name so something is still expecting this even though I changed it in the Properties >> Application >> Assembly Name box followed by a Clean / Rebuild for the entire solution.

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132991/changing-assembly-name-gives-errors)

Comment: Thanks, but having been through that link it doesn't seem applicable since there is nothing else referencing this project.  Looking at the exception it seems like it's XAML related, though I'm still struggling to figure out how or why.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132991/changing-assembly-name-gives-errors) (again)

your error is exactly what I mentioned above, when you renamed your namespace it lost the reference to the InitializeComponent method in the `MainWindow` (and usercontrols if you have any) and this is causing your error

in the image below I'll show you what I'm talking about

[image: Image 01]

image 02 is obtained by typing F12 in `MainWindow` (class)
[image: Image 02]

Comment: None of the examples I followed renamed the namespace, just the Assembly Name and the Program name.  That's what I wanted to do also, but got this error.  I only renamed the namespace as a last resort.  In the end I had to rename EVERYTHING and it worked.   Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem.  I changed the assembly name in the project properties so that my installation doesn't show the project name in Task Manager and during setup.  My (WPF) project had many references in xaml in a format like:

"/**ProjectName**;component/foo/bar.png"

I did a replace all and changed them all to:

"/**NewAssemblyName**;component/foo/bar.png"

...and everything worked after that.  I did not need to change the name of the project in VS or the namespaces.